# Flutter emulator APK contains all ABIs

Tags: flutter

I am having a project with a lot of native .so files for different ABIs.

When I am launching the Flutter Android emulator from Visual Code, it takes ages to build and install the app.

I checked the apk and it contains all the .so files for all the ABIs.

Is it possible to tell Flutter to only target the emulator ABI?

Comment: run `flutter build apk -h` command to see more advanced build options

Comment: I know I can split the APK at build time, but here I want to debug it from the IDE.

Comment: split the apk? i mean you can build for one specific target platform (so you have native libs only for that platform)

Comment: But also for flutter run?

Comment: yes, i think so

Comment: I checked, "flutter run" does not support a "--target-platform" option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flutter run` does not support specifying a target platform, however it supports passing a flavour. We can use that to workaround the problem.

Create a flavour for the emulator that filters the ABIs:

```
    flavorDimensions "abi"

    productFlavors {
        emulator {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk {
                abiFilter "x86_64"
            }
        }
        all {
            dimension "abi"
        }
    }
```

Now, by calling `flutter run --flavor emulator`, the APK will only contain the `x86_64` native libraries.

For Visual Code, the `.vscode/launch.json` can be amended to pass the flavour:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "args": [
                "--flavor",
                "emulator"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```